# Why does the WTP plugin deploy one Maven dependency as a folder, instead of a jar?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-2, eclipse-wtp

I have a very strange problem with Maven and the Eclipse WTP. I have a multi-module project, let's call it `project`. It consists of two modules `project-base` and `project-web`. I have the workspace resolution enabled (and it works fine with several other very similar Maven projects).

`project-base` is a dependency of `project-web` and it's normally deployed as a jar file. But for several days, it keeps being deployed as a class folder in my local Tomcat, as you can see here:
[image: Dependency deployed as folder, not as jar]

Therefore, my Tomcat does not recognize any of my class files in there, because it expects them to be jars, not folder.
The `-tests` suffix comes from the need to have the test from base in my web project. I don't think this is the problem.

`project-web` has three dependencies being resolved from the workspace. Two of them are deployed correctly, as jar, but the third one is not.

`project-base`'s pom.xml is shown here:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.company.project</groupId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>project-base</artifactId>
    <name>projectBase</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>windows-1251</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The dependency `project-base` as it is defined in `project-web` looks like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.company.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-base</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.company.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-base</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I don't have an idea why one dependency is deployed in such a strange way and I don't know how to fix this. I cleaned the projects, the tomcat, redeployed the web project, purged my whole Maven repository, checked out the whole project fresh from VCS, nothing helped.

What could cause Eclipse WTP to deploy this dependency as a folder instead of a jar file?

Comment: Although it doesn't explain **why**, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944278/m2eclipse-and-or-wtp-not-packaging-a-dependency-correctly) provides a work around that helped us

Comment: @chrisbunney Thank you for the information! I tried the trick, but it didn't work out for me. I removed all Eclipse specific files and let maven regenerate them, but the situation was unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately solved my problem: I had problems with the properties section *Deployment Assembly* for the `project-base` project. I could not save it, as Eclipse mentioned, the current page does contain errors.

I then looked into the settings file `.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component`. It was completely empty (I don't know why). I then added the following block:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
    <wb-module deploy-name="project-base">
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/java"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/resources"/>
    </wb-module>
</project-modules>
```

After this, the settings page is accessible again and the JAR is assembled correctly. Workspace resolution does work, too.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by deleting the dependency in the "Deployment assembly" project settings page and adding it back.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This didn'd work out for me, because I couldn't even open this exact settings page. See my answer for details.

Comment: This worked for me.... what an annoying bug. My previous work around was manually copying/pasting the jar into the deployment lib folder :/

Answer (score 2):

I was just having the same problem. Upgrading m2e to version 1.2 fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If that folder is an exploded JAR (so it is like a JAR file, but appearing as a folder, not archived), in my case it was a server connector issue.

Although I use JBoss instead of Tomcat, this might be helpful for others struggling with this problem.

Provided you have the latest JBoss Tools installed on your Eclipse, you can double-click the server in Server view to open the settings.

On **Deployment** tab, you can select **Zip Module** Yes/No for each project. When I selected YES for my utility jar files, JBoss then deployed the dependency as a normal JAR file instead of a folder.